# ImageResizer autoclean

Tags: imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I am trying to decrease ImageResizer [IR] cache size. IR are behind the CDN and for now it take about 2 days to grow up disk cache to 200Gb.
I found that there is autoclean parameter for  DiskCache plugin. I enable it on my pre-prod but it did not affect to the cache. I measure count of files after enabling autoclean:
*Yesteday, 03:53pm*
files 5944
folders 2153
*Yesteday, 07:10pm*
files 5980
folders 2199
*Today, 11:54am*
files 6382 
folders 2674

What's I am doing wrong?
Here is my Web.config:

```html
 <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="S3Reader2" prefix="~/s3" region="eu-west-1" XXX reducted XXX cacheMetadata="false" checkForModifiedFiles="true" cacheUnmodifiedFiles="true" />
      <add name="SimpleFilters" />
      <add name="AdvancedFilters" />
      <add name="DiskCache" />
      
      <add name="PdfRenderer" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />
    </plugins>
<diskcache autoclean="true" CleanupStrategy="14400"/>
    <licenses>
      <license>
        ***reducted****
      </license>
    </licenses>
  </resizer>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/diskcache

The v4 disk cache limits the quantity, not size of files. You can limit the quantity via the subfolders="" setting, which must be a power of two. Roughly 400 files are permitted per subfolder.

`<diskcache autoclean="true" subfolders="256"/>`

Comment: I would like to limit TTL for images in a cache not directly size or quantity. The goal is to store images in cache for last 4 hours.

Comment: I'd said more, I found on Github documentation for Disckcache plugin and in a HTML view not all the content of README.MD file are visible: https://github.com/imazen/resizer/tree/develop/Plugins/DiskCache
When I switched to Raw view I found required information and this solves my issue:

  <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" enabled="true"
   subfolders="8192" ....
  
  <cleanupStrategy startupDelay="00:05" minDelay="00:00:20" maxDelay="00:05" ....